# Subtracting 2 columns grouped by column

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have this table where each subject can have all days of year :

```
subject date_num value
A        123      5
B        123      3
C        123      1
A        567      9
B        567      8
C        567      3
```

For dates query between 123 and 567 I need to get :

```
subject trend
A        -4
B        -5
C        -2
```

(I get 2 rows for each subject, one for date 123, the other for date 567, and I need to subtract them, but one of the subjects **may not have a certain date - then ignore this subject**)

Tried this which failed :

```
    WITH RNG AS(
        SELECT date_num, subject, value
        FROM history
        WHERE (date_num = 1546300800 OR date_num=1635292800)
        ORDER BY date_num
    )
    SELECT date_num, subject, value,
    SUM(value) AS trend // here subtract first date value from second date value
    FROM RNG
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a self-`join`:

```
select t1.subject, t1.value - t2.value 
from subjects t1 join subjects t2 on t1.subject = t2.subject and t2.date_num = 567 where t1.date_num = 123
```

Comment: this is beautiful. Thanks a lot. can accept in 5 min